# Как вызвать Action после завершения другого Action`а в redux-thunk

Tags: reactjs, redux

Может кто подсказать как в **redux-thunk** лучше всего вызвать Action после того как завершился другой Action с запросом к API?

```
export function postCredit(uid) {
  return {
    type: CLIENT_CREDIT,
    payload: { uid },
    callAPI: `${API_URL}/client/${uid}/credit`,
  };
}
```

после того как завершится запрос к API требуется вызвать второй
`getClientMoney(uid)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Просто добавьте этот экшен к цепочке промисов.

```
const callAPI = (uid) => (dispatch, getState) => {
    return fetch(`${API_URL}/client/${uid}/credit`)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(response => dispatch(getClientMoney(response.uid))    
}
```

Comment: то есть fetch делать прям в Action`е, а не через Middleware.
Другого способа видимо нет?

Comment: @NikitaR. да для этого и нужен redux-thunk, чтобы создавать асинхронные экшены, в доках есть похожий пример. Так же перед fetch, можно диспатчить экшен, который выставит флаг `loading: false` для спинера, к примеру